# Why doesn't​ the reaction require a dehydration step after aldol formation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

During aldol formation, I've learned that there is a second addition of water in many cases to cause a dehydration to occur that results in a double bond at the alpha and beta position to the carbonyl. Why does this specific reaction automatically dehydrate? Is it due to the benzene ring?

Comment: That certainly helps because you now have an extended $\pi$ system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Biomed Boy

What do you mean by addition of 2nd molecule of water? Actually, that was not a clear statement. If you could show it in some of the mechanisms, it coul have been better to understand your doubt/question completely.
There is dehydration usually always associated with Aldol, if substrate has 2 or more (alpha) H atoms, even in absence of a Ph ring: in acid catalyzed as well as base catalyzed Aldols, though their mechanisms differ.

The reason is always a conjugated (with carbonyl) bond, which may be facilitated by a Ph ring, as in the given case.

The dehydration steps do involve:
I. In acid catalyzed Aldol, it is usual E2
[image: Acid catalysed aldol]
II. In base catalyzed Aldol, it is E1cB
[image: Base catalysed Aldol]

Comment: Why do they vote down, for no apparent reason?

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) or which need further clarification, like you imply with *"Actually, that was not a clear statement."*